# Dúvida sobre OpenSSL + Apache

Tags: php, apache, servidor, ssl, openssl

Possuo um servidor web no qual estão instalados Apache 2.4.9 e OpenSSL 1.0.1g e tenho um certificado instalado no servidor. 
Eu gostaria de atualizar o Apache e a versão do OpenSSL para Apache 2.4.16 e OpenSSL para 1.0.2d. Minha preocupação é que o certificado pare de funcionar caso eu atualize e tente instalar o certificado depois.

Posso realizar essa atualização? Existe algum arquivo (além dos certificados, chaves privadas e httpd.conf) que eu precise copiar antes da atualização?

Comment: Não há razão pro certificado deixar de funcionar, ele é independente de *webserver*. Não sei dizer de cabeça tudo o que você precisa copiar, mas creio ser o certificado em si, sua chave privada, e a cadeia de certificados raiz (no seu httpd.conf, deve estar referenciado por `SSLCertificateChainFile` e `SSLCACertificateFile`), essa podendo ser baixada do CA que assinou seu certificado.

Answer (score 0):

De fato, em princípio não haverá problema em fazer a atualização. O que poderá acontecer é ter mudado alguma diretiva dos arquivos de configuração do Apache e do OpenSSL, mas acho difícil.

Sugiro você clonar o HD com a instalação e testar a atualização eo outra máquina ou virtualizando, com Virtualbox, por exemplo.